# Appium Execution Error: A new session could not be created

Tags: java, eclipse, appium

I am unable to identify any solution to my problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Set the Desired Capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy J7 Max");
        caps.setCapability("udid", "4200cd5b9bdf8423"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1.0");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "me.com.easytaxi");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "me.com.easytaxi.presentation.dashboard.DashboardActivitys");
        caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");

        //Instantiate Appium Driver
        try {
                AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error after executing above code.

> **Appium server Error logs:**
>   A new session could not be created.(Original error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\Users\sasaleem1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4200cd5b9bdf8423 shell \"ps 'uiautomator'\"\"\nps: uiautomator\r\n)","killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null,"cmd":"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\Users\sasaleem1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4200cd5b9bdf8423 shell \"ps 'uiautomator'\"\"","origValue":"Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\Users\sasaleem1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4200cd5b9bdf8423 shell \"ps 'uiautomator'\"\"\nps: uiautomator\r\n"},"sessionId":null}

///////////////////////////////////////////////

> info: Client User-Agent string: selenium/3.141.59 (java windows)
>   warn: Converting cap noReset from string to boolean. This might cause unexpected behavior.
>   info: [debug] Didn't get app but did get Android package, will attempt to launch it on the device
>   info: [debug] Creating new appium session 1cd44b3e-bab0-494b-b77e-ee052699a463
>   info: Starting android appium
>   info: [debug] Getting Java version
>   info: Java version is: 1.8.0_201
>   info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
>   info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Users\sasaleem1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   warn: No app capability, can't parse package/activity
>   info: [debug] Using fast reset? false
>   info: [debug] Preparing device for session
>   info: [debug] Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on the device
>   info: Retrieving device
>   info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sasaleem1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
>   info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: Found device 4200cd5b9bdf8423
>   info: [debug] Setting device id to 4200cd5b9bdf8423
>   info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sasaleem1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4200cd5b9bdf8423 wait-for-device
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sasaleem1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4200cd5b9bdf8423 shell "echo 'ready'"
>   info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sasaleem1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4200cd5b9bdf8423 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 27
>   info: Device API level is: 27
>   info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
>   info: [debug] Apk doesn't exist locally
>   info: [debug] Could not get strings, but it looks like we had an old strings file anyway, so ignoring
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sasaleem1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4200cd5b9bdf8423 shell "rm -rf /data/local/tmp/strings.json"
>   info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
>   info: [debug] Skipping install since we launched with a package instead of an app path
>   info: [debug] Forwarding system:4724 to device:4724
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sasaleem1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4200cd5b9bdf8423 forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724
>   info: [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sasaleem1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4200cd5b9bdf8423 push "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\android_bootstrap\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/
>   info: [debug] Pushing settings apk to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sasaleem1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4200cd5b9bdf8423 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk"
>   info: [debug] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sasaleem1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4200cd5b9bdf8423 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk"
>   info: Starting App
>   info: [debug] Attempting to kill all 'uiautomator' processes
>   info: [debug] Getting all processes with 'uiautomator'
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sasaleem1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4200cd5b9bdf8423 shell "ps 'uiautomator'"
>   info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM
>   info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
>   warn: UiAutomator did not shut down fast enough, calling it gone
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
>   error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "C:\Users\sasaleem1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4200cd5b9bdf8423 shell "ps 'uiautomator'""
>   ps: uiautomator
>
> info: [debug] Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "C:\Users\sasaleem1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4200cd5b9bdf8423 shell "ps 'uiautomator'""
>   ps: uiautomator
>
> ```
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
> at maybeClose (child_process.js:1016:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1088:5)
> ```
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\Users\sasaleem1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4200cd5b9bdf8423 shell \"ps 'uiautomator'\"\"\nps: uiautomator\r\n)","killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null,"cmd":"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\Users\sasaleem1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4200cd5b9bdf8423 shell \"ps 'uiautomator'\"\"","origValue":"Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\Users\sasaleem1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4200cd5b9bdf8423 shell \"ps 'uiautomator'\"\"\nps: uiautomator\r\n"},"sessionId":null}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 22328.083 ms - 732

Comment: can you add full appium server log?

Comment: @SubanDhyako I added full appium server logs above.

Comment: @stackoverflow please help me resolving this issue I can't find solution anywhere for this above error.

Comment: which appium version are you using?